# Different sounds for different alarms

Tags: alarm, custom-sounds

Is there a way (app, root code, etc) to set a different alarm sound for each alarm?

Comment: What phone do you have? The AOSP alarm clock has this as a built-in feature, but the manufacturer of your phone may have replaced it with their own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option is Sleep Bot. you can choose an alarm sound for each alarm, you can have plenty of alarms with different labels, you can also choose individually the snooze time.and the seconds you want the alarm to sound!!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this app is your answer: [GM Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.alarm.activity) as mentioned in google play, this app has different alarm sounds and you can select the option for random alarm sounds each day. and the alarm sound will not repeat as it maintains a history for previous alarm sounds. Might be useful for you.

Comment: also try [alarm clock plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vp.alarmClockPlusDock) this app has a lot of options too!

Comment: thanx! I'll give them a try!
I'm now wondering, is it possible to set a playlist as alarm? or to play a random tune from it or a folder?

Comment: if you want playlist as your alarm tunes. [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hotrod.utility.playlistalarm) is your tool for the task you require.